# werid, same expression yield different value when excuting two times in irb

Tags: ruby, regex

```
irb(main):051:0> "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/,"#{$1} ?")  
=> "ts_id > ?"
irb(main):052:0> "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/,"#{$1} ?")
=> "ts_id < ?"
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: you can not use $1 in a gsub expression http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `$1` is interpolated into the argument string *before* `gsub` is run, meaning that the *previous* value of `$1` is what the symbol gets replaced with. You can replace the second argument with `'\1 ?'` to get the intended effect.

Comment: I wish I know English so good to tell the main idea so short and understandable "$1 is interpolated into the argument string before gsub is run..."

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0>  "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/,"#{$1} ?")
=> "ts_id  ?"
irb(main):002:0>  "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/,"#{$1} ?")
=> "ts_id < ?"
```

Note, that I used fresh started irb, where the `$1` was `nil`. That's all because when using `.gsub(...,..$1..)`, when calculatings the "part right from `,`" the `$1` is not generated by "left part from `,`" yet.

So do this:

```
irb(main):001:0> "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/,'\1 ?')
=> "ts_id < ?"
```

Or this:

```
irb(main):001:0> "ts_id < what".gsub(/(=|<|>)\s?(\w+|\?)/){"#{$1} ?"}
=> "ts_id < ?"
```