# Why doesn't this Ruby replace regex work as expected?

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider the following string which is a C fragment in a file:

```
strcat(errbuf,errbuftemp);
```

I want to replace errbuf (but not errbuftemp) with the prefix G-> plus errbuf. To do that successfully, I check the character after and the character before errbuf to see if it's in a list of approved characters and then I perform the replace.

I created the following Ruby file:

```
line = " strcat(errbuf,errbuftemp);"  
item = "errbuf"  
puts line.gsub(/([ \t\n\r(),\[\]]{1})#{item}([ \t\n\r(),\[\]]{1})/, "#{$1}G\->#{item}#{$2}")
```

Expected result:

```
strcat(G->errbuf,errbuftemp);
```

Actual result

```
strcatG->errbuferrbuftemp);
```

Basically, the matched characters before and after errbuf are not reinserted back with the replace expression.

Anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you must use syntax `gsub(/.../){"...#{$1}...#{$2}..."}` or `gsub(/.../,'...\1...\2...')`.

Here was the same problem: [werid, same expression yield different value when excuting two times in irb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829273/werid-same-expression-yield-different-value-when-excuting-two-times-in-irb/)

> The problem is that the variable $1 is interpolated into the argument string before gsub is run, meaning that the previous value of $1 is what the symbol gets replaced with. You can replace the second argument with '\1 ?' to get the intended effect. *(Chuck)*

Comment: Right on, looked through the thread you provided and came up with:  
 
    puts line.gsub(/([ \t\n\r(),\\[\\]]{1})#{item}([ \t\n\r(),\\[\\]]{1})/){"#{$1}G\->#{item}#{$2}"}

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is the use of gsub() instead of sub().

Here's two alternates:

```
str = 'strcat(errbuf,errbuftemp);'

str.sub(/\w+,/) { |s| 'G->' + s } # => "strcat(G->errbuf,errbuftemp);"
str.sub(/\((\w+)\b/, '(G->\1') # => "strcat(G->errbuf,errbuftemp);"
```

Comment: If I reverse errbuf and errbuftemp in the input string, your code will append G-> to errbuftemp rather than errbuf. I'm looking to ignore errbuftemp and process errbuf only - hence the peeking at the character before and after in my original regex.

Appreciate the fact that you took some time to provide an answer, though.

Comment: Ah, well that wasn't a prerequisite in the question. I had a sample that does follow errbuf. Check the #1 edit and you should see it.